# Keyerror with bs4: return self.attrs[key] KeyError: 'src'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


URL = "https://ww0.jujutsukaisen.online/manga/jujutsu-kaisen-manga-chapter-1/?2022-12-29"

r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

images = soup.find_all('img')



for image in images:
    name='name'
    link = image['src']
    print(link)
```

`

Error in Pycharm

```
C:\Users\amicr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe D:\Junk\Scrape.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Junk\Scrape.py", line 17, in <module>
    link = image['src']
  File "C:\Users\amicr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1519, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'src'
```

It gives me the same error every time
I want to download all the images from that site and this is only *learning purpose*

Comment: You have a `img` tag without a `src` attributes. You could do the check `if 'src' in image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this specific page, the image either has the `src` or the `data-src` attribute within the tag. You can look for `'src'` or `'data-src'` in the `attributes` before calling the code, to avoid generating an error.

#### Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://ww0.jujutsukaisen.online/manga/jujutsu-kaisen-manga-chapter-1/?2022-12-29"

r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for img in soup.find_all('img'):
    if 'src' in img.attrs:
        print(img['src'])
    elif 'data-src' in img.attrs:
        print(img['data-src'])
```

#### Output:

```
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/001.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/002.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/003.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/004.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/005.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/006.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/007.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/008.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/009.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/010.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/011.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/012.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/013.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/014.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/015.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/016.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/017.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/018.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/019.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/020.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/021.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/022.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/023.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/024.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/025.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/026.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/027.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/028.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/029.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/030.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/031.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/032.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/033.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/034.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/035.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/036.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/037.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/038.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/039.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/040.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/041.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/042.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/043.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/044.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/045.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/046.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/047.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/048.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/049.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/050.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/051.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/052.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/053.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/054.jpg
            
            https://img.spoilerhat.com/img/?url=https://s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/mangazone/1001279/055.jpg
//pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-YjnCnfhzH9Gef.gif
```